# SVN in Linux using Active Directory

Tags: svn, active-directory

We are currently trying to setup a svn server that will require authentication with AD. I have found many articles online talking about this but most are using apache to handle the AD authentication. Are there any howto's when using the svn protocol instead of apache?

We are using the svnserver that comes with subversion module.

We are not wanting to change the servers authentication method to use AD, just svn.

Answer (score 4):

From [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.svnserve):

> If you need to integrate with existing legacy identity systems 
>   (LDAP, Active Directory, NTLM, X.509, etc.), you must use either
>   the Apache-based server or svnserve configured with SASL."

So I'm guessing you want to [configure svnserve with SASL](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sasl).

This has been asked before: [SVN + SASL + ActiveDirectory: How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794242/svn-sasl-activedirectory-how-to)

Comment: Thank you for the info. It seems like i will just go the Apache route.